# How to determine branches involved in a merge?

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

I have a scenario where I need to Identify a merge event and the source and destination branch of this merge.

So, that I can take some actions based on the type of source branch( i.e. feature/bugfix/hotfix etc).

Are there any git commands or scripts for that?

Comment: This is certainly not possible in general (a branch is just a reference to the latest commit on that branch – the history is assumed from the predecessors of the commit). It is however possible to come close – take a look at the output of `git log --graph`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I normally use below command :

git log --graph --full-history --all --pretty=format:"%h%x09%d%x20%s"

Comment: thankyou @love Can I also generate an HTML report of the same so that I can see the things clearly?